# TypeError: input() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, typeerror

```
workouts=int(input("How many workouts do you have data for?\n"))
a=0
b=0

for i in range(workouts):
    sets=int(input("How many sets were completed in workout #",a,"?\n", sep=""))
```

I'm trying to create a for loop that runs for the amount of workouts i specify, that then asks me how many sets i would do. However, i get an input error instead.

Comment: No; you get a `TypeError` that tells you about the `input` function. The problem is that you are expecting to be able to use `input` the same way as `print`, but that's not actually how it works. The `print` function is special. When you give a prompt for `input`, it has to be a single string. Please see the linked duplicate in order to understand how to assemble the string that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Inputs require + str(var), they can't use commas in this case